# primefaces datatable rowEditor error

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, roweditor

I'm using JSF 2.2 and primefaces 4.0 with Mojarra 2.2.2 on a Tomcat server.
I'm using a p:datatable with a row editor, but whenever I try to edit a row I get the following error when press the "check" button to save the changes:

```
may 17, 2014 10:17:03 PM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
Información: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.queueEvent(DataTable.java:666)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:486)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

may 17, 2014 10:17:03 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
Advertencia: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:270)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.queueEvent(DataTable.java:666)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:486)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
    ... 26 more

may 17, 2014 10:17:03 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
Grave: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.queueEvent(DataTable.java:666)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:486)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1740)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

this is the part of the xhtml page with the dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="nombreAsociados" 
                             var="asociado" 
                             value="#{nuevaInscripcionBacking.asociados}" 
                             editable="true" 
                             emptyMessage="Aún no ha agregado asociados">
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" 
                            update=":#{cc.attrs.id}:formularioNewIns:distDerechosAsoc"  
                            partialSubmit="true"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Rut">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{asociado.rut}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputMask value="#{asociado.rut}" mask="99.999.999-*" style="width:100%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Nombres">  
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{asociado.nombre}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText value="#{asociado.nombre}" style="width:100%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>  


                    <p:column headerText="Apellido Paterno">  
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{asociado.apellidoPaterno}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText value="#{asociado.apellidoPaterno}" style="width:100%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Apellido Materno">  
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{asociado.apellidoMaterno}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText value="#{asociado.apellidoMaterno}" style="width:100%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Rol Predio">  
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{asociado.rolPredio}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText value="#{asociado.rolPredio}" style="width:100%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:6%" rendered="#{nuevaInscripcionBacking.ventana==1 || nuevaInscripcionBacking.ventana==3}">  
                        <p:rowEditor />  
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width: 6%" rendered="#{nuevaInscripcionBacking.ventana==1 || nuevaInscripcionBacking.ventana==3}">
                        <p:commandLink id="eliminar" 
                                       oncomplete="PF('DialogRemoveAsoc').show()"
                                       update=":#{cc.attrs.id}:formEliminarAsociado"
                                       process="@this"
                                       partialSubmit="true"
                                       styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"> 
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                                value="#{asociado}" 
                                target="#{nuevaInscripcionBacking.asociadoAEliminar}" />
                        </p:commandLink> 
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

The last column is to delete the row. It actually works fine.
In the code above, the list I use to iterate is of objects "Asociados", which is just a bean with it's corresponding getters and setters.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible show us the nuevaInscripcionBacking class and nuevaInscripcionBacking.asociados variable?probably problem is from one of the field type...For example, you input float to int type or string to date.type mismatching

Comment: Hosein Masbought, thank you for your answer. Yes I thought that too but all fields are string, and I input only strings. Also I noticed that when I remove the <p: ajax .../> tag inside the datatable the problem dissapears and I'm able to edit correctly

Comment: @HoseinMasbough thank you. I've solved the issue. It turns out that I wasn't using primefaces 4.0 I was using 5.0 SNAPSHOT that I had to download to add Graphis to it. I downloaded the latest version, which is 5.0. I realized this error after looking at [this page](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36400)